# Broadcast receiver called 2 times when turning off GPS?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive...");
        if(intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS provider changed...");
            EventBus.getDefault().postLocal(intent.getAction());
        }
    }

}:
```

Comment: Edit the `Log.d(TAG, "onReceive...");` to this -> `Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction();` to see why is called twice :)

Comment: The same both times: android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem but I did't find root of problem.It seems device or OS version specific problem.

To know that the message has been called, you could have a static boolean that gets toggled between connect and disconnect and only call your sub-routines when you receive a connection and the boolean is true. Something like:

```
  private static boolean firstConnect = true;

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
      //Receive called twice because of device or OS version specific issue.  
      final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

      if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

          //enable
          if(firstConnect){
              sendStatus("on",context);
              firstConnect=false;
          }

      }else{

          //disable
          if(!firstConnect){
              sendStatus("off",context);
              firstConnect=true;
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Solution code

```
public class MyBroadcastReceivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static boolean isGpsEnabled,isPermissionAskedOnce=true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGpsEnabled = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            

            if(isGpsEnabled){
                   //do you stuff
                    isPermissionAskedOnce=true;
            }else{
                 
                if(isPermissionAskedOnce){
                  //do your stuff 
                    isPermissionAskedOnce=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Why not check whether the GPS provider is enabled in your receiver?

```
lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: One should not have time consuming calls in onReceive. I'm sending and event via EventBus and now it's sent two times. In the event receiver I have the code you provide. But it still does not answer my question...